Title: "Uncaught TypeError: this._component is null in createAnimatedComponent.tsx:541 after upgrading to Expo SDK 50
I'm facing an issue after updating my Expo project to SDK 50. The error displayed is:
Uncaught TypeError: this._component is null
This error originates from the file node_modules/react-native-reanimated/lib/module/createAnimatedComponent.tsx at line 541.
